# Why didn't Voldemort use Legilimency further to actually hear the prophecy in Harry's head?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, prophecy

In Order of the Phoenix, this dialogue happens shortly before Voldemort duels Dumbledore in the Ministry Atrium:

> “Don’t waste your breath!” yelled Harry, his eyes screwed up against the pain in his scar, now more terrible than ever. “He can’t hear you from here!”

> “Can’t I, Potter?” said a high, cold voice.

> Harry opened his eyes.

> Tall, thin, and black-hooded, his terrible snakelike face white and gaunt, his scarlet, slit-pupiled eyes staring . . . Lord Voldemort had appeared in the middle of the hall, his wand pointing at Harry who stood frozen, quite unable to move.

> “So you smashed my prophecy?” said Voldemort softly, staring at Harry with those pitiless red eyes. “No, Bella, he is not lying. . . . **I see the truth looking at me from within his worthless mind**. . . . Months of preparation, months of effort . . . and my Death Eaters have let Harry Potter thwart me again. . . .”

> “Master, I am sorry, I knew not, I was fighting the Animagus Black!” sobbed Bellatrix, flinging herself down at Voldemort’s feet as he paced slowly nearer. “Master, you should know —”

The bolded phrase shows that Voldemort used Legilimency to know if Harry was lying about the status of the prophecy. Since he could look deep into someone's memories really well, like he did with Gregorovitch to know who stole the Elder Wand despite that memory in Gregorovitch's head happening almost a century ago, and countless other examples, why didn't he look deeper into Harry's mind and learn what the prophecy actually says?

Answer (score 11):

I may be completely misunderstanding the question, but as far as I can tell, the scene you are describing happens before Harry himself knows what the prophecy says. He learns that from Dumbledore a bit later. So there is nothing for Voldemort to read.